# .htacces redirect to https://www.; to instead of one redirection

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I have multiple domains I want to do the same with. Let's take the domain `example.com`.

I always want to redirect to `https://www.[mydomain]`.

In this case: `https://www.example.com`.

I need to redirect:

```
https://example.com

http://www.example.com

http://example.com
```

to

```
https://www.example.com
```

To do so, I have this code:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule .* https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

For `https://example.com` and `http://www.example.com` redirection is directly to `https://www.example.com`.

But for `http://example.com` redirection goes to `https://example.com` and then to `https://www.example.com`, instead of going directly to `https://www.example.com`. There are two redirections.

Why that? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 2 options here.

Use a single rule for both redirections like this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]
```

Or else change order of your rules to this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]
```

Whatever option you chose remember to clear your browser cache or use a new browser for testing.

Comment: I prefer first one since there is a single rule so in theory `mod_rewrite` will execute that faster.